# Making proper integral for shaded region

Tags: geometry

> I have curve and line, one curve is a parabola intersects at $(-3,0)$, $(-1,0)$, and $(0,1)$ while the line intersects at $(-3,0)$ and $(0,2)$.
>
> *Sorry I couldn't upload the picture, but I could describe about the shaded region between these curve and line.*
>
> 1. (**Condition 1**) The area between $(-3,0)$, $(-1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(0,2)$ is **shaded**. The peak of parabola below $x$-axis is **not shaded.**
> 2. (**Condition 2**) The area between $(0,1)$, $(0,2)$, and $(a,b)$ is **shaded**. The $a$ must be the value of $x$ when factorized the parabola equation (because $x=-3$ is already here). I don't think the $b$ will be used.

I need to find the area of the shaded region.

Here is my attempt:

I got the equation for the parabola and curve. The parabola is $y=\frac{1}{3}(x+1)(x+3)$ and the line is $y=\frac{2}{3}x+2$, then I defined the integrals are below:

$A_{1}$ is area of Condition 1. This is just integral of the line, which is $$\int_{-3}^{-1}\,{\frac{2}{3}x+2-0}\,dx$$
The 0 is from $y=0$ ($x$-axis).

$A_{2}$ is area of unshaded region between $(-1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(0,0)$. The integral is
$$\int_{-1}^{0}\,{\frac{1}{3}(x+1)(x+3)}-0\,dx$$
$A_{3}$ is area of Condition 2. I already got the $a=1$. The integral is subtracting $\mathrm{line-parabola}$, which is
$$\int_{0}^{1}\,{-x^{2}-3x+3}\,dx$$

So the area of shaded region would be
$$A_{1}-A_{2}+A_{3}$$

Is my attempt true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you want to find the area of the gray part in the following figure :

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Then, your attempt is not true. The area is given by
$$\int_{-3}^{-1}\left(\frac 23x+2\right)dx+\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\left(\frac 23x+2\right)-\left(\frac 13x^2+\frac 43x+1\right)\right)dx$$